# Find lines of file with multi patterns

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I want to find lines of a file that have special patterns and print them in another file.
For example:

```
a(code(4),message(h),b)

x(code(6),6)

v(message(d),b)
```

I want below output:

```
4 h

6

d
```

It means if code and message parts exist, values of them print and if one of them exists, print only that one

EDIT:
I have lines like :

```
ereport(ERROR,(errmsg("database hash table corrupted during cleanup --- abort")));

ereport(FATAL,(errcode(ERRCODE_OBJECT_NOT_IN_PREREQUISITE_STATE),errmsg("data directory \"%s\" has wrong ownership",DataDir),errhint("The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.")));
```

I need below output:

```
database hash table corrupted during cleanup --- abort

ERRCODE_OBJECT_NOT_IN_PREREQUISITE_STATE[tab]data directory \"%s\" has wrong ownership[tab]The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

These are error messages in PostgreSQL and I want to find list of them.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and how it failed and we'll help.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about what you did to solve the problem.
Anyways you have got your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
4 h
6
d
```

It will not work on your real data

Answer (score 1):

for the above example this code will extract the data as you want:

```
for i in `cat data.txt`
do
    echo $i | grep -E 'message|code' | sed 's/^.(//' | sed 's/code(//' | sed 's/,[a-z])//' | sed 's/,message(//' | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's/)/ /' | sed 's/)//' | sed 's/message(//'
done
```